# Calling a function which has a numeric value assigned to it for query

Tags: postgresql, function

Here instead of using 7 days interval, I want to use `days_gap` in a function and pass a `numeric` value to it instead of a hardcoded value. And then directly call it in the `SELECT` function

```
SELECT BOO_NUMBER,
      ROO_NUMBER
    FROM BOO B
    WHERE B.FOO < CURRENT_TIMESTAP - '7 days'::interval
```

Instead of using `'7 days'::interval` I want to use a function `days_gap` which takes a numeric value in the function and can be called respectively instead of 7 days interval.

Please help me with the function code to be called in the select query.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
SELECT BOO_NUMBER,
      ROO_NUMBER
    FROM BOO B
    WHERE B.FOO < CURRENT_TIMESTAP - interval '1 day' * days_gap()
```

Comment: I need a code for `days_gap()` which takes a number.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [`make_interval()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#id-1.5.8.14.5.2.2.22.1.1)?

```
SELECT boo_number,
       roo_number
FROM boo b
WHERE b.foo < current_timestap - make_interval(days => 7);
```

Note that you can always multiply a one day interval with the desired number of days as well:

`interval '1 day' * 7` is the same as `interval '7 day'`